# Replacing newline character in a field in csv file

Tags: csv, awk, sed, tr

I have a `CSV file` with 165 columns and I have a problem. 
I need to replace `\r\n` characters with a blank space from the columns but not from the end of line as it is the record separator.

Input:

```
001|Baker St.
London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane
Liverpool|88|5|7
```

Output:

```
001|Baker St. London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7
```

I am using a windows script but I am open to using `UnxTools (gawk, sed, tr)` or whatever it's needed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. First of all, thank you for the anwer but I think I didn't explain correctly. \r\n are the carriage return and newline characters, not literally \r\n.

Comment: OK now I see: you want to join multiline fields. Check my updated answer.

Comment: It works like a charm with my 165 field CSV. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to group multi line fields. In that case, let's manually store the string until it is "big enough", that is, until it has enough fields to know the record is complete:

```
awk -F"|" -v fields=5 '{f+=NF; str=(str?str OFS:"") $0}
                       f>=fields{print str; str=""; f=0}' file
```

With `-v fields=5` we indicate how many fields a proper line should contain. Then, we keep storing data in the `str` variable until it has at least `fields` fields.

Note also that you are working with a Windows file. To work properly in UNIX, first convert it to this format by using `dos2unix file`. This will convert `\r\n` into `\n`.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F"|" -v fields=5 '{f+=NF; str=(str?str OFS:"") $0} f>=fields{print str; str=""; f=0}' file
001|Baker St. London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7
```

---

(Old version, when it looked like you needed to remove literal `\r\n`)

Just make sure something appears after `\r\n`, so that end of line is not matched:

```
$ sed -r 's/\\r\\n(.)/ \1/g' file
001|Baker St. London|3|4|7\r\n
002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7\r\n
```

This looks for `\r\n` plus another thing and prints that other thing back after a space.